# Counting lines with lego mindstorms ev3?

Tags: arrays, ipad, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

So I have to count lines with the lego mindstorms ev3 robotor. I have to use the iPad app to make the programm, and I just can‘t figure it out. Would apreciate some tips and in the best case, I would like to get the full programm with maybe a screenshot :).
Ty all for the answers!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.